# disabled qtablewidgetitem is not shown gray

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidgetitem

i have a `qtablewidgetitem` and inside it there is a `QCheckbox`

when disabling `qtablewigetitem` as follow

```
    flags = self.item(row+1, self.columns["USER_ACCESS"]).flags()
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    self.item(row+1, self.columns["USER_ACCESS"]).setFlags(flags)
```

it is disabled and i can't click on it but it is dispalyed as it stills enabled.

i want to display it colored in gray

**UPDATE:**

```
class CheckBoxDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning QCheckBox in every
    cell of the column to which it's applied
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        '''
        Important, otherwise an editor is created if the user clicks in this cell.
        ** Need to hook up a signal to the model
        '''
        return None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        '''
        Paint a checkbox without the label.
        '''

        checked = index.data() #.toBool()
        check_box_style_option = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()

        if (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable) > 0:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled
        else:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_ReadOnly

        if checked:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_On
        else:
            check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Off

        check_box_style_option.rect = self.getCheckBoxRect(option)

        #if not index.model().hasFlag(index, Qt.ItemIsEditable):
        check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_ReadOnly

        check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled

        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_CheckBox, check_box_style_option, painter)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        '''
        Change the data in the model and the state of the checkbox
        if the user presses the left mousebutton or presses
        Key_Space or Key_Select and this cell is editable. Otherwise do nothing.
        '''
        if not (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable) > 0:
            return False

        # Do not change the checkbox-state
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
          return False
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease or event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton or not self.getCheckBoxRect(option).contains(event.pos()):
                return False
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() != QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and event.key() != QtCore.Qt.Key_Select:
                return False
            else:
                return False

        # Change the checkbox-state
        self.setModelData(None, model, index)
        return True

    def setModelData (self, editor, model, index):
        '''
        The user wanted to change the old state in the opposite.
        '''
        newValue = QtCore.Qt.Checked if not index.data() else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        model.setData(index, newValue, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.parent.sort()
        self.parent.sort()

    def getCheckBoxRect(self, option):
        check_box_style_option = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        check_box_rect = QtGui.QApplication.style().subElementRect(QtGui.QStyle.SE_CheckBoxIndicator, check_box_style_option, None)
        check_box_point = QtCore.QPoint (option.rect.x() +
                            option.rect.width() / 2 -
                            check_box_rect.width() / 2,
                            option.rect.y() +
                            option.rect.height() / 2 -
                            check_box_rect.height() / 2)
        return QtCore.QRect(check_box_point, check_box_rect.size())
```

and here is how i put it inside the QTableWidgetItem

```
def delegate(self, column, delegater):
    self.setItemDelegateForColumn(column, delegater)
    pass
```

Comment: Why don't you use the normal way ...?

Comment: Or use semi-colons?  Also looks like you're setting it to enabled to me.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic, Python doesn't need to line break with semi-colons.

Comment: I missed the PyQt tags. ;)

Comment: Yeah. They werent there when you commented. I recently added them :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `^` instead.

```
flags ^= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

`|` is the bitwise-OR. What it does is turns the enabled flag ON regardless of its original state.
`^` will toggle it.

If you want to TURN OFF the flag REGARDLESS of its original state, just AND (&) it with its COMPLIMENT (~) like so:

```
flags = flags & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

You can apply these principles of any flags that you want to turn off or on, like `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable` etc.

In your case, the code would be something like:

```
flags = self.item(row+1, self.columns["USER_ACCESS"]).flags()
flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
self.item(row+1, self.columns["USER_ACCESS"]).setFlags(flags)
```

Check out this for more details:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Another wonderful answer that touches on this topic (very useful):
[How to find specific Qt.ItemFlag occurrence into custom Qt.ItemFlags instance in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616329/how-to-find-specific-qt-itemflag-occurrence-into-custom-qt-itemflags-instance-in/13616444#13616444)

***UPDATE-1:***
If your cells have items in the form of *Widgets* (egs. `QCheckBox`), you might want to approach it differently. You might want to disable the corresponding *widget* instead. So in your case you would do something like:

```
my_checkbox_item = self.cellWidget(row+1, self.columns["USER_ACCESS"])
my_checkbox_item.setEnabled(False)
```

***UPDATE-2:***
Since, you have now updated your question with more code, here's another update:
In your `paint` method you have to apply the same bitwise operation principles as illustrated in the first part of this answer. So you would have to do something like:

```
    if (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable) > 0:
        check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled
        check_box_style_option.state &= ~QtGui.QStyle.State_ReadOnly
    else:
        check_box_style_option.state &= ~QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled
        check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_ReadOnly
```

.. and REMOVE these lines:

```
    #if not index.model().hasFlag(index, Qt.ItemIsEditable):
    check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_ReadOnly

    check_box_style_option.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled
```

That should fix it.

Comment: this was very helpful but it stills shown white and not gray! i can't click it or check it

Comment: That is bizarre. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Actually I think I see a problem here. I ll update my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Can you share how you are setting each item? Just the code for setting each item. Are you setting a `QCheckBox` as the cells using `setCellWidget()`?

Comment: i updated my post and added the full code of my checkbox-delegator

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if that worked out for you. It should.